# Why not using cross validation for estimating the error of a linear model?

Tags: regression, linear-model

Cross validation (CV) seems to be a simple and useful tool for estimating the out-of-sample error of a linear regression model, even though it is rarely used for this purpose.
Why that? Is there a better ways for error estimation?
Is it possible to estimate the out-of-sample error by only using the training data?

Comment: You need to state your ultimate goal.  For linear models we  have a closed-form expression for an unbiased estimate of residual variance if you are honest about the predictor degrees of freedom in its denominator.

Comment: "honest about the predictor degrees of freedom" ... which can become difficult if the data has (or possibly has) a clustered structure. And yes, depending on what you want/need to measure, other procedures may be more appropriate.

Comment: Perhaps, but a bit more important is that all the predictors were pre-specified and none was deleted by seeming to be 'unimportant'.  Otherwise, d.f. needs to be the 'effective d.f.' as in http://www.citeulike.org/user/harrelfe/article/13265069

Comment: Given the assumptions that go into the closed-form expression and the potential to run into the multiple comparisons problem before you even choose what to regress on, is it not usually better to rely on cross-validation and a test set to estimate the predictive power of a linear model?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I see it used quite often in fact. Note that the popular predicted residual error sum of squares (PRESS) statistic calculated from the residuals & diagonal elements of the hat matrix is what you'd get by performing leave-one-out cross validation.

Alternatives to cross-validation include splitting the sample into training & test sets, & bootstrapping to estimate the optimism in any measure of fit & then correcting for it. See Steyerberg et al. (2001), "Internal validation of predictive models: efficiency of some procedures for logistic regression analysis", *Journal of Clinical Epidemiology*, **54**, pp 774 – 781 for a comparison. Splitting the sample isn't a good idea unless you have a large sample size (in the tens of thousands, I've heard).

Comment: In analytial chemistry it is used so often that the measures get their name accordingly: e.g. $RMSE_{CV}$